# Can't flush DataOutputStream in Java

Tags: java, arrays, dataoutputstream

I want to put a double array into DataInputStream and print it with DataOutputStream in console. I tried to convert it to byte array first.
I can't flush() DataOutputStream, so it gets printed in console. 
System.out.print(c) works.

```
double[] b = { 7, 8, 9, 10 };

//double[] to byte[]
byte[] bytes = new byte[b.length * Double.SIZE];
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
for (double d : b)
    buf.putDouble(d);
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(System.out);

int c;
try{
    while( (c = dis.read()) != -1){
        //System.out.print(c);
        dos.writeInt(c);
    }
    dos.flush();
}
catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("error: " + e);
}
```

Output with System.out.print(c), what I want to achieve: `642800000064320000006434000000643600000000000000000000000000000000[...]`

Comment: You can use ByteBuffer.allocate(b.length * Double.SIZE)

Comment: It is unclear from your question what you want to do exactly; can you provide a sample input and the expected output?

Comment: I can see some output, but it's binary data. I guess, whether you see it or not depends on your terminal. Try to redirect it to file.

Comment: I have redirected it to a file, and it prints a chunk of data, but still it is invisible in console (eclipse).

Comment: The byte would generate unprintable characters on consoles such as eclipse console. That's why there are `base64` encoders in the world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing bytes to console may cause control characters( that can not be printed) and would cause unexpected result. If you absolutely need to see the text representation, you would consider ASCII converters such as Base64.

But in your example, replace

`dos.writeInt(c);` with `dos.writeChars(Integer.toString(n));`

and you will get expected result. `writeInt` writes 4 bytes representing current int and that can result in various control characters. `writeChars` writes a sequence of characters instead.